# reshape vs. reshape2 in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am attempting to understand why development had shifted from `reshape` to `reshape2` package. They seem to be functionally the same, however, I am unable to upgrade to `reshape2` currently due to an older version of R running on the server.  I am concerned about the possibility of a major bug that would have shifted development to a whole new package instead of simply continuing development of `reshape`.  Does anyone know if there is a major flaw in the `reshape` package?

Comment: `reshape2` replaced `reshape`. But what is your question?

Comment: You found the official docs right? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf How about this explanation of how to use reshape2? http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Manipulating%20data/Converting%20data%20between%20wide%20and%20long%20format/

Comment: yes, i saw the official docs. will take a look at your second link, thanks. i am trying to figure out what changed? how is `reshape2` different than `reshape`?

Comment: Reshape was on old version of a package.  From what I've observed Hadley Wickham is pretty concerned with breaking the code of people relying on his packages.  I'm guessing reshape needed some major overhauls, rather than breaking everyone's code eh started over from scratch (I'm guessing). There's a few differences in functions and usage but they do very similar kobs.  I'd recommend you stick with reshape2 as I don't believe reshape is being developed anymore.

Comment: @Maiasaura, I can't upgrade to reshape2 because my sys admin runs an old version of R. Therefore, I needed to know if there was some major bug that caused Hadley to build reshape2.

Comment: So it sounds like your real (and answerable) question is: "Did Hadley Wickham shift his efforts to **reshape2** because of a major bug in **reshape**?"

Comment: @JoshO'Brien yes, i guess that is true. i'd be happy to revise if you think that is best.

Comment: I think that'd be great. Someone who knows can clearly answer that question (probably with reference to some notes Hadley made about the matter).  Cheers.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`reshape2` let Hadley make a rebooted `reshape` that was way, way faster, while avoiding busting up people's dependencies and habits.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-packages/2010/001169.html

> Reshape2 is a reboot of the reshape package. It's been over five years
>   since the first release of the package, and in that time I've learned
>   a tremendous amount about R programming, and how to work with data in
>   R. Reshape2 uses that knowledge to make a new package for reshaping
>   data that is much more focussed and much much faster.
>
> This version improves speed at the cost of functionality, so I have
>   renamed it to `reshape2` to avoid causing problems for existing users.
>   Based on user feedback I may reintroduce some of these features.
>
> What's new in `reshape2`:
>
> - considerably faster and more memory efficient thanks to a much
>     better    underlying algorithm that uses the power and speed of
>     subsetting to the    fullest extent, in most cases only making a
>     single copy of the data.
> - cast is replaced by two functions depending on the output type:
>     `dcast`    produces data frames, and `acast` produces matrices/arrays.
> - multidimensional margins are now possible: `grand_row` and
>     `grand_col` have    been dropped: now the name of the margin refers to
>     the variable that has    its value set to (all).
> - some features have been removed such as the `|` cast operator, and
>     the    ability to return multiple values from an aggregation function.
>     I'm    reasonably sure both these operations are better performed by
>     plyr.
> - a new cast syntax which allows you to reshape based on functions
>     of variables (based on the same underlying syntax as plyr):
> - better development practices like namespaces and tests.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Appreciate you posting this from the mail list to the more publicly familiar forum here.

Comment: *the ability to return multiple values from an aggregation function* See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477040/reshape2-multiple-results-of-aggregation-function