# In R, how do I create consecutive ID numbers for each repetition in a separate variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to R and to programming in general. I've just begun to learn how to use for loops, but I can't figure out how to get the variable I want to print as part of my dataframe.

I have data that look like this:

```
Place  Sex  Length
A      M    32
A      M    33
A      F    35
A      F    35
A      F    35
A      F    39
B      M    30
B      F    25
B      F    28
B      F    28
```

I would like to create a fourth variable in my dataframe that gives each line of data a unique identifier that is specific to it's `Place/Sex/Length` combination so that my data look like this and so each individual has a unique `Place/Sex/Length/ID` combination that is specific to that line of data only:

```
Place  Sex  Length Ind
A      M    32     1
A      M    33     1
A      F    35     1
A      F    35     2
A      F    35     3
A      F    39     1
B      M    30     1
B      F    25     1
B      F    28     1
B      F    28     2
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.  I've been searching for a while for some help on how to do this with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

One (of many) ways is to use `ave` in base R, as follows (assuming a `data.frame` named "temp")

```
within(temp, {
  ID <- ave(as.character(interaction(temp)), 
            interaction(temp), FUN = seq_along)
})
#    Place Sex Length ID
# 1      A   M     32  1
# 2      A   M     33  1
# 3      A   F     35  1
# 4      A   F     35  2
# 5      A   F     35  3
# 6      A   F     39  1
# 7      B   M     30  1
# 8      B   F     25  1
# 9      B   F     28  1
# 10     B   F     28  2
```

Try running `interaction(temp)` to get an idea of what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
# assuming the data.frame is already sorted by 
# all three columns (unfortunately, this is a requirement)
> sequence(rle(do.call(paste, df))$lengths)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 2
```

Break down:

```
do.call(paste, df) # pastes each row of df together with default separator "space"
#  [1] "A M 32" "A M 33" "A F 35" "A F 35" "A F 35" "A F 39" "B M 30" "B F 25" "B F 28"
# [10] "B F 28"

rle(.) # gets the run length vector 
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:7] 1 1 3 1 1 1 2
#   values : chr [1:7] "A M 32" "A M 33" "A F 35" "A F 39" "B M 30" "B F 25" "B F 28"

$lengths # get the run-lengths (as opposed to values)
# [1] 1 1 3 1 1 1 2

sequence(.) # get 1:n for each n 
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 2
```

---

## Benchmarking:

Since there are quite a few solutions, I thought I'd benchmark this on a relatively huge `data.frame`. So, here are the results (I also added a solution `data.table`).

Here's the data:

```
require(data.table)
require(plyr)
set.seed(45)

length <- 1e3 # number of rows in `df`
df <- data.frame(Place = sample(letters[1:20], length, replace=T), 
                 Sex = sample(c("M", "F"), length, replace=T), 
                 Length = sample(1:75, length, replace=T))
df <- df[with(df, order(Place, Sex, Length)), ]
```

Ananda's `ave` solution:

```
AVE_FUN <- function(x) {
    i <- interaction(x)
    within(x, {
        ID <- ave(as.character(i), i, FUN = seq_along)
    })
}
```

Arun's `rle` solution:

```
RLE_FUN <- function(x) {
    x <- transform(x, ID = sequence(rle(do.call(paste, df))$lengths))
}
```

Ben's `plyr` solution:

```
PLYR_FUN <- function(x) {
    ddply(x, c("Place", "Sex", "Length"), transform, ID = seq_along(Length))
}
```

At last, the `data.table` solution:

```
DT_FUN <- function(x) {
    dt <- data.table(x)
    dt[, ID := seq_along(.I), by=names(dt)]
}
```

Benchmarking code:

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(d1 <- AVE_FUN(df), 
          d2 <- RLE_FUN(df), 
          d3 <- PLYR_FUN(df), 
          d4 <- DT_FUN(df), 
 replications = 5, order = "elapsed")
```

Results:

With `length = 1e3` (number of rows in data.frame df)

```
#                 test replications elapsed relative user.self 
# 2  d2 <- RLE_FUN(df)            5   0.013    1.000     0.013 
# 4   d4 <- DT_FUN(df)            5   0.017    1.308     0.016 
# 1  d1 <- AVE_FUN(df)            5   0.052    4.000     0.052 
# 3 d3 <- PLYR_FUN(df)            5   4.629  356.077     4.452
```

With `length = 1e4`:

```
#                test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 4   d4 <- DT_FUN(df)            5   0.033    1.000     0.031
# 2  d2 <- RLE_FUN(df)            5   0.089    2.697     0.088
# 1  d1 <- AVE_FUN(df)            5   0.102    3.091     0.100
# 3 d3 <- PLYR_FUN(df)            5  23.103  700.091    20.659
```

With `length = 1e5`:

```
#                test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 4   d4 <- DT_FUN(df)            5   0.179    1.000     0.130
# 1  d1 <- AVE_FUN(df)            5   1.001    5.592     0.940
# 2  d2 <- RLE_FUN(df)            5   1.098    6.134     1.011
# 3 d3 <- PLYR_FUN(df)            5 219.861 1228.274   147.545
```

Observation: The trend I notice is that with bigger and bigger data, `data.table` (not surprisingly) does the best (scales really well), while `ave` and `rle` being quite close competitors for second place (`ave` scales better than `rle`). `plyr` performs quite bad on all datasets, unfortunately.

Note: Ananda's solution gives `character` output and I kept it as such in the benchmarking.

Comment: Don't include the creation of the data.table in the function. `dt[,ID := seq_len(.N), by = names(DT)]` may also be faster

Comment: @mnel, I remember MatthewDowle mentioning something similar to include `, key(.)` to be fair [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182888/complicated-reshaping). I assumed it should include creating the data.table under the comments to Ricardo's benchmarking.

Comment: if you want to take advantage of the sorting and speed-up from setting the key, then include the setkey(), but you aren't in this case, so I think it is unfair overhead (as opposed to  fair overhead if you were setting the key)

Comment: The speed seems to be almost the same (0.149 with .N, 0.151 seconds with .I for 1e5 rows). The results are identical (sorry for the earlier wrong report).

Comment: @Arun, thanks for the benchmarks. Pretty interesting. `ave` *might* scale even faster if your `do.call(paste...` approach is used instead of `interaction`, or, specifying `drop = TRUE` in `interaction` to drop unused factor levels.

Answer (score 3):

The inevitable `plyr` solution.

Get data:

```
temp <- read.table(text="
Place  Sex  Length
A      M    32
A      M    33
A      F    35
A      F    35
A      F    35
A      F    39
B      M    30
B      F    25
B      F    28
B      F    28",
header=TRUE)
```

Load package and Do It:

```
library("plyr")
ddply(temp,c("Place","Sex","Length"),transform,ID=seq_along(Length))
```

The order has changed (you can use `arrange()` to re-order it if you want), but the variables should be right:

```
##        Place Sex Length ID
## 1      A   F     35  1
## 2      A   F     35  2
## 3      A   F     35  3
## 4      A   F     39  1
## 5      A   M     32  1
## 6      A   M     33  1
## 7      B   F     25  1
## 8      B   F     28  1
## 9      B   F     28  2
## 10     B   M     30  1
```

Comment: I just benchmarked on relatively bigger data.frames.. and `plyr` seems to perform quite badly. Please check my post for the results.

Comment: It's nice to have the benchmarks -- but it's also not really surprising. `plyr` was designed (AIUI) for conceptual simplicity and convenience, not necessarily raw speed. Unlike many of the SO user base, I don't live in a Big Data world -- I can live with 5 seconds for a 1000-row data frame ... but `data.table` and base-R solutions are certainly worth considering if one does have a need for speed ...