# Recast in R with sum+product

Tags: r, casting, aggregation, reshape, reshape2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
x   y   value   weight
10  1   red 1
3.4 5   blue    2
10  10  blue    0.5
3   8   blue    0.5
3   8   red 4
10  1   blue    1
3   8   blue    2
3   8   blue    0.25
```

I want to recast it so that each row is a unique combination of "x" and "y", and the columns are the sums of the "weight"s for each different value of "value". If possible, I'd *also* like to have columns for raw counts of the values of "value". So for these data that would be:

```
x   y   red_count   blue_count  red_sum_of_weights  blue_sum_of_weights
10  1   1   1   1   1
3.4 5   0   1   0   2
10  10  0   0   1   0.5
3   8   1   3   4   2.75
```

Is there a way to do this with reshape or reshape2? I can get it to do counts of the values with

```
dcast(data,x+y~value)
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to use the weights in the way I want it to. I need this to work with an arbitrary number of possible levels for value and an arbitrary different number of rows per x*y combination in the original dataset. I've written my own code just using for loops to do this, but it takes an *extremely* long time to run - so far has taken 6 hours to do the first 15% of a 600k row dataset, which isn't very practical! But I'm sure there must be a way to do this with existing functions?

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: For counts, add `fun.aggregate=length` (although that's the default, so it should do that anyway if you have more than one value in at least one cell).

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! Yes, I realise that's the default, which is why, as I mentioned, I've been able to use dcast(data,x+y~value) to get raw counts. What I can't work out is how to get the sums of values from "weight" for each distinct value of "value".

Comment: If you were just using `dcast`, it would be `fun.aggregate=sum`, but in your case you need a combination of split-apply-combine functions. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `dplyr` and `reshape2` functions. First, group by `x`, `y` and `value` (we change the name of the latter to `color` only to avoid duplicate column names after melting) and then calculate the count and sum for each sub-group. Then `melt`the result to put the newly calculated summaries in "long" format. Finally, `dcast` to get the "wide" format you asked for.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(x,y,color=value) %>% 
  summarise(count=n(), sum=sum(weight)) %>%
  melt(id.var=c("x","y","color")) %>%
  dcast(x + y ~ variable + color)
```

> ```
>      x  y count_blue count_red sum_blue sum_red
> 1  3.0  8          3         1     2.75       4
> 2  3.4  5          1        NA     2.00      NA
> 3 10.0  1          1         1     1.00       1
> 4 10.0 10          1        NA     0.50      NA
> ```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to use functions in the tidyr package as opposed to those in reshape2?

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks very much! Works perfectly :D I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @AlexIoannides see the answer from Steven Beaupré.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x, y, value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n(), sum = sum(weight)) %>%
  gather(key, val, -(x:value)) %>%
  unite(newkey, value, key) %>%
  spread(newkey, val)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
#Groups: x, y [4]
#
#      x     y blue_count blue_sum red_count red_sum
#* <dbl> <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1   3.0     8          3     2.75         1       4
#2   3.4     5          1     2.00        NA      NA
#3  10.0     1          1     1.00         1       1
#4  10.0    10          1     0.50        NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution using `data.table::dcast`:

```
require(data.table)
dcast(dt, x + y ~ value, value.var = "weight", fun.aggregate = list(length, sum))
#       x  y weight_length_blue weight_length_red weight_sum_blue weight_sum_red
# 1:  3.0  8                  3                 1            2.75              4
# 2:  3.4  5                  1                 0            2.00              0
# 3: 10.0  1                  1                 1            1.00              1
# 4: 10.0 10                  1                 0            0.50              0
```

where,

```
dt = fread('x   y   value   weight
           10  1   red 1
           3.4 5   blue    2
           10  10  blue    0.5
           3   8   blue    0.5
           3   8   red 4
           10  1   blue    1
           3   8   blue    2
           3   8   blue    0.25
           ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with the data table :

```
require(data.table)

count=dcast(df,x+y~paste(value,"_count",sep=""))
weights=dcast(df,x+y~paste(value,"_sum_of_weights",sep=""),value.var = "weight",fun.aggregate = sum)
result=merge(count,weights,by=c("x","y"))
```

Result:

```
    x  y blue_count red_count blue_sum_of_weights red_sum_of_weights
 10.0  1          1         1                1.00                  1
 10.0 10          1         0                0.50                  0
  3.0  8          3         1                2.75                  4
  3.4  5          1         0                2.00                  0
```

Although I have to admit it would have been much simpler if we could use two functions in dcast. Supposedly you can but I keep getting an error... 
After some digging I found a very nice answer in this thread [reshape2: multiple results of aggregation function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477040/reshape2-multiple-results-of-aggregation-function) which defines a wrapper function for dcast as follows:

```
dcastMult <- function(data, formula, value.var = "value", 
                   funs = list("min" = min, "max" = max)) {
  require(reshape2)
  if (is.null(names(funs)) | any(names(funs) == "")) stop("funs must be named")
  Form <- formula(formula)
  LHS <- as.character(Form[[2]])
  if (length(LHS) > 1) LHS <- LHS[-1]
  temp <- lapply(seq_along(funs), function(Z) {
    T1 <- dcast(data, Form, value.var = value.var, 
                fun.aggregate=match.fun(funs[[Z]]), fill = 0)
    Names <- !names(T1) %in% LHS
    names(T1)[Names] <- paste(names(T1)[Names], names(funs)[[Z]], sep = "_")
    T1
  })
  Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), temp)
}
```

Using this lovely function we get the result as follows:

```
result=dcastMult(df,x+y~value,funs = list("count"=length,"sum_of_weights"=sum),value.var = "weight")
```

Comment: `data.table::dcast` allows multiple `value.var` and `fun.aggregate`.. I've posted an answer.

Comment: Yes you are right! I just had not updated the version of data table on that machine. Side question: Can you set the names in the result data table somehow?