# Why ggplot2, reshape2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is just something thats been bugging me since I started learning R.

What does the naming convention stand for in the package `ggplot2`? `reshape2` is described here [reshape vs. reshape2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377334/reshape-vs-reshape2-in-r). Basically, there originally was a base package `reshape` that has been improved and the latest iteration is `reshape2`,

but why the `2` in `ggplot2`?

Comment: I am totally unsure about that, but I thought there was a `ggplot` package, which was completely rewritten afterwards. To underline incompatibility between these packages, `2` was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same reason. Check this tweet by ggplot2's author:
https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/424286541704216576

Comment: I also found this link on cran http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot/